# After downloading a file in firefox, the little "folder-button" to get to Download directly does not work in Ubuntu22.04

Tags: firefox, downloads

The file downloads, it is listed in the "Downloads-list" in Firefox (little arrow in the menu bar), but when clicking on the folder symbol next to the downloaded file, the Download folder does not open. So I have to open it manually from my file manager to access my downloaded file.

Does anybody know a solution (or has the same problem)?

I installed Firefox as a snap, and also updated it already, but the problem persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on 22.04, I would recommend installing the APT version instead.
**WARNING:You would lose all your data(history, bookmarks and settings) so make sure to sync firefox with your Mozilla account**

- Add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

- Prevent APT from reverting to the snap version during install/upgrade

```
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox

echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

- Install Firefox

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

- Remove the snap version of firefox(after syncing it to your Mozilla account):

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Then to restore your data, sync your APT version of firefox.

**WHATEVER YOU DO, YOU SHOULD CONSIDER CREATING A BUG REPORT TO MOZILLA**.